# Stand Alone Qt app with lapack/blas on windows (and other missing dlls)

Tags: c++, qt, lapack, blas, msys2

I developed a app on QT using armadillo with Lapack, Blas and Lapacke. It run on my QT (running on MSYS2 - MingW32), but when i try build a stand alone with windeployqt, apparently works. But when i tried run, it give missing .dll (liblapack.dll, libblas.dll,libstdc++-6.dll and libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll).

I don't know what i can do to fix it.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [the help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately windeployqt has some issues on MSYS2/MinGW. For starters you need to enable the --compiler-runtime command line option to get libstdc++-6.dll and libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll, but probably it's not enough. See for example this issue for further details: https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/221.
The conclusion is that you're better off with using also an other tool (like ldd) together with windeployqt and some clever scripting to copy all of the needed .dll-s into your deployment.